# Generating and Displaying labels and corresponding textboxes at runtime?

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate labels and corresponding textboxes at runtime after fetching data from tables.How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a panel or div in the page and create the controls in the code behind. Add these controls to the panel/div something like below.

```
Label testLabel = new Label();
testLabel.ID = "TestLabel";
testLabel.Text = "Test";
this.TestPanel.Controls.Add(testLabel);

TextBox testTextBox = new TextBox();
testTextBox.ID = "TestTextBox";
this.TestPanel.Controls.Add(testTextBox);
```

Hope this Helps!!